# how to select two table and merge the data not to show the duplicate

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

Is it possible to achieve the following result set?

table1:

```
id_s  name   post_code     city     amount1
------------------------------------------
1     name1  postal1    city1    300
2     name2  postal2    city2    400
3     name3  postal3    city3    NULL
4     name4  postal4    city4    NULL
```

table2:

```
id_p  name   post_code     city     Amount2
------------------------------------------
1     name1  postal1    city1    300
2     name2  postal2    city2    NULL
3     name3  postal3    city3    400
5     name5  postal5    city5    500
```

result set:

```
id_s  name   post_code     city     amount1  amount2
------------------------------------------
1     name1  postal1    city1    300         300
2     name2  postal2    city2    400         NULL
3     name3  postal3    city3    NULL        400
4     name4  postal4    city4    NULL        NULL
5     name5  postal5    city5    NULL        500
```

Comment: That's a simple `OUTER JOIN`

Comment: Very odd table design. Why do you store so similar data in two separate tables? What if same id_p but different names/cities etc?

Comment: Could we provide a correct solution to your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
        COALESCE(table_1.id_s, table_2.id_p) as id
       ,COALESCE(table_1.name, table_2.name) as name
       ,COALESCE(table_1.post_code, table_2.post_code) as post_code
       ,COALESCE(table_1.city, table_2.city) as city
       ,table1.amount1
       ,table2.amount2
FROM table1
FULL OUTER JOIN table2 ON table_1.id_s = table_2.id_p
```

> **OUTER JOIN**: 
>   The FULL OUTER JOIN keyword returns all the rows from the left table (table1), and all the rows from the right table (table2). If there are rows in "table1" that do not have matches in "table2", or if there are rows in "table_2" that do not have matches in "table1", those rows will be listed as well.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp

> **COALESCE**:
>   Evaluates the arguments in order and returns the current value of the first expression that initially does not evaluate to NULL.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
    DECLARE @table1 TABLE
    ( id_s INT, name NVARCHAR(20), post_code NVARCHAR(20), 
city NVARCHAR(20), amount1 NVARCHAR(20) )
    DECLARE @table2 TABLE
    ( id_s INT, name NVARCHAR(20), post_code NVARCHAR(20), 
city NVARCHAR(20), amount2 NVARCHAR(20) )

    INSERT INTO @table1 VALUES
    ('1'     ,'name1',  'postal1',    'city1',    '300'),
    ('2'     ,'name2',  'postal2',   'city2',    '400'),
    ('3'     ,'name3',  'postal3',    'city3',    NULL),
    ('4'    ,'name4',  'postal4',    'city4',    NULL)

    INSERT INTO @table2 VALUES
    ('1',     'name1', 'postal1',    'city1',    '300'),
    ('2',     'name2',  'postal2',    'city2',    NULL),
    ('3',     'name3',  'postal3',    'city3',    '400'),
    ('5',     'name5',  'postal5',    'city5',    '500' )

    SELECT * FROM @table1

    SELECT * FROM @table2  

    SELECT 
    ISNULL(t1.id_s,t2.id_s) id_s, ISNULL(t1.name,t2.name) name,
    ISNULL(t1.post_code,t2.post_code) post_code, ISNULL(t1.city,t2.city) city,
    amount1,amount2
     FROM @table1 t1 FULL JOIN @table2 t2 ON t1.id_s = t2.id_s
```

This will give you perfectly the result you looking for.

Hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 3):

A `full outer join` should do the job:

```
SELECT          COALESCE(id_s, id_p),
                COALESCE(table1.name, table2.name),
                COALESCE(table1.post_code, table2.post_code),
                COALESCE(table1.city, table2.city),
                amount1,
                amount2
FROM            table1
FULL OUTER JOIN table1 ON id_s = id_p
```